# CoreNLP for Original Dependencies with Neural Network Dependency Parsing

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I use Stanford CoreNLP v 3.5.2 in order to get Neural Network Dependency Parsing.

The problem is I don't need Universal Dependencies I need original Dependencies.

Properties file can have **parse.originalDependencies** attribute, however there two questions

NN DepParsing is **depparse** option, and the attributes of **depparse** are not described in http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml

I am not sure that **depparse.originalDependencies** exists.

In addition, how exactly should I define it in properties file

```
depparse.originalDependencies = 1
or 
depparse.originalDependencies = true
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a different parsing model using the `-depparse.model` option in your CoreNLP invocation. (Note that if you are accessing the parser directly through the `edu.stanford.nlp.parser.nndep.DependencyParser` class, this option is just called `-model`.)

Use the following `-depparse.model` option. This refers to a non-Universal Dependencies model that is distributed with the parser.

```
-depparse.model "edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/english_SD.gz"
```